# MS Access Queries to SQL Server Views/Proc/Trigger

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

This is general question. I'm migrating MS Access DB where a table is created from 3 different tables using multiple update , select , delete and alter statements in several steps. When we are migrating to SQL Server what will be the best approach ?
I know this can't be accomplished in a view.

Answer (score 0):

Use MS Access to connect to an external data-source, your SQL Server, then you can select from your Access tables directly into your SQL Server tables

Comment: Each month the data gets update so the logic should be kept intact. I created views for several other queries. But this table has multiple operations performed in 6 steps to create the table. The steps are run from a Macro.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like each month you creating a NEW table. This likely a bad idea, and makes reporting over several months VERY difficult, and forces a BIG list of issues likely having to change the table name in quires etc. You likely best have ONE table were you send the results to and THEN query by date range or using month(dateColumn) and year(dateColumn) to pull out the one month. So you likely having difficulty finding a solution because such solutions that need to create a NEW table each month or for each time some “process” is run also tend to be a “difficult” solution and one rarely required or used.

So I don’t think the issue is creating a table, the issue is much thinking like a spreadsheet and “saving” a months worth of data into a NEW table each time.

So I would dump the idea of creating these new tables all the time and come up with a design that eliminates this requirement.

In fact if your Access back end database was a linked database, then this approach in Access would have also been VERY challenging also – especially in a multi-user environment.

So the real answer here is to avoid the monthly table creating. You find then you can care FAR better reporting on such data, and can thus report over multiple time periods (as opposed to trying to read data from multiple tables of the SAME structure).

So create ONE table to hold the results for each run, and add a column that differentiates the data in that table for each run. It makes little sense to have the Month/Year in the table name and create 12 tables for a year as opposed to adding a simple date column to the ONE table.

And often even better is to adopt a system that quires the LIVE data and eliminates all this sending of data to some table.

It possible you talking about a temp “scratch” table for data processing? You can send some data to a temp table that is tossed out, but then again that simply means you don’t need to create a table on the fly every time you run those 6 steps.

So your cut + paste approach to data process, or the “idea” of making a copy of a spreadsheet data into a new month approach is one that works poorly for data processing.

This creating table each time is especially prone to maintains issues if the system is to be used in a multi-user environment.

If a new table has to be created each time your process is run, then some design changes to how this process works is like your better solution.

Last but not least: it is possible that I am misunderstand your goal, but feel free to expand on the “6” steps of data processing you have and where “eventually” the results of this data is supposed to land.

Comment: The table is created from text files on monthly basis. I have a SSIS jobs for it. There are some operations performed on the loaded data for creating several other tables. Most of them i have created them as views. But some need several steps. So i would use the Ssis again in different data flow. Between is there any transformation for update strategy. I know it can be accomplished in execute SQL task.

Comment: No issues I see UNLESS you plan to create new tables each month on SQL server. Do you plan to add the these new links every month to Access also? This is VERY messy approach. If you saying you plan to cunrch data to some local Access tables and THEN upload to exiting SQL server tables, then no problem. However creating new tables server side that you keep is really a spreadsheet approach and not one that works for data processing solutions.

Comment: The tables are not created every month. They are just loaded fresh via SSIS from flat files. The tables have fixed link to the FE.